# warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch in VSC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm learning about C++ but i have some problem when i want to run my code ...

```
int __cdecl Voter___Vote(Voter *_this, CPlayer *pOne, char *pdata){

CPlayer *pPlayer=(CPlayer *)pOne;
CPvpOrderView * Pvp=GetPvpOrderViewV(pPlayer);
char tmp1[255];
char tmp2[255];
char tmp3[255];
char tmp4[255];
itoa(pPlayer->m_Param.m_dbChar.m_byLevel,tmp1,10);
sprintf(tmp2, "%Lf", Pvp->m_dPvpPoint>=PvpPoint);
sprintf(tmp3, "%Lf", Pvp->m_dPvpPoint>=PvpCash);
itoa(pOne->m_pUserDB->m_AvatorData.dbAvator.m_dwTotalPlayMin>=TotalPlayMin,tmp4,10);
MessageBoxA(NULL,tmp2 ,tmp3,MB_OK); 
if(pPlayer->m_Param.m_dbChar.m_byLevel>=Lvl&&Pvp->m_dPvpPoint>=PvpPoint&&Pvp->m_dPvpCash>=PvpCash&&
    pOne->m_pUserDB->m_AvatorData.dbAvator.m_dwTotalPlayMin>=TotalPlayMin)
{return     p_Vote(_this,pOne,pdata);}
return 10;
}
```

and i have some error like this

```
Vote.cpp
Vote.cpp(42): warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
Vote.cpp(45): warning C4018: '>=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

Comment: Those are warnings (not errors) - they tell you that you are comparing signed and unsigned values. This is not *usually* a serious problem but you should fix it anyway, either by correcting the underlying types, or when all else fails by using suitable casts.

Comment: @PaulR That's good advice but personally I regard it as a potentially very serious problem indeed. Undefined behaviour is only a whisker away.

Comment: @Bathsheba: unfortunately this kind of signed/unsigned mismatch is so common that most compilers don't even generate a warning for it unless you turn the warning level up to "11". But I agree, there are cases where this kind of comparison can be fatal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning means that the signedness of the variables you're comparing are different.

To fix this you could cast the unsigned variable to a signed type:

```
itoa(static_cast<signed>(pOne->m_pUserDB->m_AvatorData.dbAvator.m_dwTotalPlayMin)>=TotalPlayMin,tmp4,10);
```

I am assuming the `m_dw*` variables are `DWORD`'s which means they are 32-bit unsigned integers.

You could also cast the signed variable to an unsigned type:

```
itoa(pOne->m_pUserDB->m_AvatorData.dbAvator.m_dwTotalPlayMin>=static_cast<unsigned>(TotalPlayMin),tmp4,10);
```

This works fine too, but it depends on wether or not you *know* that `TotalPlayMin` always will be a positive number.

Edit: note that I'm not actually sure I got the right line since I can't see the line numbers in your code and there are also quite a lot of >= comparisons in there.

Comment: Using a cast should really be the last resort - it can often just mask a problem rather than fixing it - better to fix the underlying problem (by correcting the data types) than just covering it up and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing signed/unsigned is dangerous. Quite contr-intuitively you will find that small netgative signed values are bigger than unsigned:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = -11;
    unsigned int b = 42;

    if ( a < b ) {
            printf("a<b\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("a>=b\n");
    }
}
```

this prints out:

```
a>=b
```